# How to run BigQueryInsertJobOperator as dynamic task using expand

Tags: google-bigquery, airflow, airflow-2.x

In task `process_dag_json_create_upd_sql` , I am reading a SQL file with multiple `update table set` queries from GCS as string. Then splitting the string into list of queries. The list is returned.

```
process_dag_json_create_upd_sql = PythonOperator(
        task_id="process_dag_json_create_upd_sql",
        provide_context=True,
        python_callable=process_dag_json_create_upd_sql,
        trigger_rule=TriggerRule.ALL_DONE,
        op_kwargs={'domain_l0': domain_name_l0, 'sys_prof_param_list': get_sys_profile_param.output,
                   'tgt_proj_id': target_project_id, 'comp_bucket': composer_bucket,
                   'tgt_temp_bucket': target_temp_bucket, 'tmp_file_name': upd_sql_file_name
                   }
    )
```

Now I want to create a dynamic task using `BigQueryInsertJobOperator` , where for each  query in the list (returned from previous task), one instance of the dynamic task should get created.

```
exec_upd_query = BigQueryInsertJobOperator.partial(
        task_id=f"upd_ing_conf",
        location='us-east4',
        configuration={
            "query": {
                "query": query,
                "useLegacySql": False,
            }
        }
    ).expand(query=process_dag_json_create_upd_sql.output)
```

But it is not accepting the `query` argument value to create the dynamic task.
The error is `Unresolved reference 'query'`

Please advise.

Thanks
Santanu

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create airflow dynamic task using BigQueryInsertJobOperator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78005651/how-to-create-airflow-dynamic-task-using-bigqueryinsertjoboperator)