# How to create airflow dynamic task using BigQueryInsertJobOperator

Tags: google-bigquery, airflow, airflow-2.x

I want to create Airflow Dynamic Task using `BigQueryInsertJobOperator` to run multiple SQL queries. There should be multiple instances of the task based on the list of queries.

I tried below code, but it is giving error.

Task:

```
exec_upd_query = BigQueryInsertJobOperator.partial(
        task_id=f"upd_ing_conf",
        location='us-east4'
    ).expand(configuration={'query': {"query": ["Q1", "Q2"], "useLegacySql": False}})
```

Error:

```
TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Thanks,
Santanu

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of the possibility of running multiple queries in a single task, this does not seem very optimal or maintainable.

I can offer you two approaches:

- Save the content of those queries in your /data or /queries under your Dag folder.
- Save those queries in BigQuery itself under Saved queries and record their IDs.

Once you do the above;

- Either Parse .sql files you have stored using pure Python and create a group task where each query would be a sub-task.
- Have a variable in Airflow for the stored query ids and create a dynamic task where again each query would be a sub-task.

Please check the following documentation regarding Dynamic tasks. https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/authoring-and-scheduling/dynamic-task-mapping.html

This way, Dynamic tasks would enable you to re-run any step/query that failed or needed to be re-triggered for some reason without running all the queries saving you from redundant costs. You can specify the number of tasks/queries to run in parallel.

Below is a sample code on how you can do the first approach.

```
path = "/home/airflow/gcs/dags/queries"

def list_sql_files(directory_path):
    sql_files = []
    for filename in os.listdir(directory_path):
        if filename.endswith(".sql"):
            sql_files.append(os.path.join(directory_path, filename))

    return sql_files

def get_query(query_name, path):
    return open(f"{path}/{query_name}.sql".format(query_name = query_name)).read()


with TaskGroup(group_id='bq_queries') as tg1:
    for sql_path in list_sql_files(path):
        name = base_name = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(sql_path)) 
        ..... 
        # here you would parse the query using the above get_query function 
         # and then your operator and the execution would come.
         # You can use the name of the file maybe as the task name.
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What I have understood, the first approach "Save the content of those queries in your /data or /queries under your Dag folder" will require external DAG triggering where we can loop over the SQL file and create task group with sub tasks. For the 2nd approach, could you please share example of how to save BQ query from airflow and record their ids ?

Comment: You do not need a separate dag to parse the .sql files. You can do this within your original dag, basically when the dag's schedule kicks in, create the dynamic tasks within a for loop where the query of the task would be what you have parsed from the file. 

For the second approach, you can follow the [documtn] (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/procedures) and once you create your queries, use the id of the query which is mydataset.create_customer() to be called within Airflow as CALL mydataset.create_customer();